# SQL - Usar valor de where em outra where

Tags: sql

Olá
Não sou programador, apenas um curioso desenvolvendo uns relatorios basicos do sistema da empresa.

Gostaria de saber se consigo usar os valores de um where (das notas faturadas) em outra where (dos pedidos realizados).
Estou agrupando os pedidos realizados por vendedores em um periodo e as notas faturadas daquele vendedor naquele mesmo periodo, mas essas informações são de tabelas diferentes.
Uso um editor basico que roda dentro do proprio sistema. Tentei fuçar com declaração de variaveis, mas aparentemente ele não aceita o "@".

Abaixo segue o procedimento:

```
Select 
a.vendedor,
a.NNotas,
a.VNotas,
b.NPed,
b.VPed
from(select s.vendedor, Count(s.saida_id) NNotas, sum(s.valorproduto) VNotas
from saida s
WHERE extract(month from S.DATA) = :pmes and extract (year from S.DATA) = :pano AND s.ativo='Y'  AND S.natureza=0
group by s.vendedor) as A
Inner Join (select p.vendedor, Count(p.pedido_id) NPed,
sum(p.valorproduto) VPed
From pedido p
WHERE extract(month from P.DATA) = 11 and extract (year from P.DATA) =2020 and (p.tipovenda in ('00001','00004','00005','00011','00013'))
group by p.vendedor) As B On a.vendedor = b.vendedor
```

Desse jeito consigo os resultados , porém preciso colocar o mes e o ano 2 vezes...uma para faturamento, outra para pedidos.

Fico no aguardo.
Obrigado

Comment: você não consegue repetir o :pmes e o :pano?

Comment: Me desculpe ...colquei o codigo com os valores 11 e 2020...era um teste. Na vdd o que devia ter passado tinha pmes e pano nos 2 where. Dai qdo rodo...ele pede para eu colocar 2x o mes e 2x o ano....POdendo o usuario colocar meses e anos diferentes. Que pra uma comparação futura poderá ser util. Mas no momento preciso que carregue o mesmo mes e ano

Comment: Qual banco de dados e versão é utilizado?

Answer (score 0):

Se o banco de dados for **ORACLE** pode usar **DEFINE**

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve017.htm

Ferramenta que utilizo para gerenciar o DB

http://www.sqltools.net/

Exemplo: use a v_cod onde precisar conforme abaixo

```
DEFINE v_cod = 3;
SELECT * 
  FROM
      ( 
        SELECT 1 COD,'PRIMEIRO' DESCR FROM DUAL UNION
        SELECT 2,'SEGUNDO'       FROM DUAL UNION
        SELECT 3,'TERCEIRO'      FROM DUAL UNION
        SELECT 4,'QUARTO'        FROM DUAL UNION
        SELECT 5,'QUINTO'        FROM DUAL
      )
 WHERE COD = &v_cod
```

Answer (score 0):

O que você pode fazer também e utilizar um **SELECT** dentro do do **WHERE**. Assim o retorno desse SELECT vai ser disponível para vc utilizar no **WHERE**.
Mas ou menos assim:

```
 SELECT first_name, last_name FROM customers WHERE customer_id =                 
 (SELECT customer_id FROM customers WHERE last_name = 'Brown');
```

Lembrando que você vai ter que limita um pouco o **SELECT** do **WHERE** para pode retorna somente o valor da **COLUNA** que você deseja utilizar .

Referencia:
https://imasters.com.br/back-end/como-fazer-subconsultas-um-passo-passo